# In Windows 10 21H2, how to change the target of a folder shortcut if the Shortcut tab is not available in Properties dialog?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, user-interface, dialog, properties

In Windows 10 21H2, how to change the target of a folder shortcut if the Shortcut tab is not available in Properties dialog?

I googled but had no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the "shortcut' has an actual size. It's not a shortcut, but instead a symbolic link. You can delete it and create a new one on the command line using `mklink` (requires an elevated Command Prompt):

```
mklink /D path\to\link path\to\target
```

In contrast to a regular shortcut, this will be seen by programs just like a regular folder (which regular links are not).